# Redefine a named range to a different cell in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range in Excel that is a single cell. I can't figure out how to change the range to a different cell.

Currently 'myEOR' range is A150. I would like to set 'myEOR' to A160. It seems like this would be simple, but I can't figure out the syntax in VBA.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
Sub ChangeNamedRange()
Dim rng As Range, nameStr As String
nameStr = Application.InputBox("Mention the name (address of which) to be edited", _
                Default:="myEOR", Type:=2)
'OR in procedure ... nameStr = "myEOR"
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select new range for 'myEOR' named range", _
                Type:=8)
'OR in procedure ... Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10")
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=nameStr, RefersTo:="=" & _
                rng.Parent.Name & "!" & rng.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: If myEOR name is not present this code will add the name with rng range. Otherwise, it will change the referred address of myEOR name to the rng address

Comment: This is definitely the path I need to take. Thank you. 

How would I modify that so that the range has the scope of a worksheet and not the workbook?

Comment: For name scope for Sheet1, replace `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add` with `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Names.Add`

Comment: Thank you I figured it out. I was having issues with the worksheet name because there were spaces in the name. I forgot to add the ' in statements like "'Sheet Name"". I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the existing syntax, you could get the idea about the syntax stored in named-range.

[image]

I could go on and explain everything, but i think that would take away the fun.

p/s: take note there is a `=` sign.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Set myEOR = Range("A160")
myEOR = "myEOR"
Names.Add Name:=myEOR, RefersTo:=myEOR
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```vb
ThisWorkbook.Names("myEOR").RefersTo = ActiveSheet.Range("A160")
```